FLA UI ComboBox with item template
I'm using Fla UI with WPF.
I have a ComboBox with an ItemsSource that is a List of instances of a class type, and then the ComboBox has a non trivial ItemTemplate (simplified here)
e.g
public class Vehicle
{
   public int PropA { get; }
   public string PropB { get; }
   public string PropC { get; }
}

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Vehicles}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropA }" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropB }" ForeGround="Red" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropC }" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

In general, with a 'not string based' itemsSource, how do you generally write the selection from the test?
For example, how would I select a particular vehicle?
I'm trying to avoid doing it based on index, as that could change.
